# Custom .htaccess 404 page for Plesk (Linux)

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, centos, plesk

I'm using CentOS linux server with Plesk Control panel. I created custom **.htaccess** in *root/home folder* of my domain name to set custom 404 page but it not working.

I tried

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

and

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^404/?$ /404.php [L]
```

Both didn't worked perfectly but sometime it work partially, Like

```
example.com/wrongurl -> Custom 404 page -> working
example.com/wrongurl.html -> custom 404 page -> working
example.com/wrongurl.php -> default 404 - Not working
```

Mainly for **.php** it loading default plesk 404 instead of my custom 404 page.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: IMHO `ErrorDocument 404 /404.php` should be Good enough for documents for 404 error code, could you please confirm if your 404.php is present in your root directory? Since you mentioned `/` before `404.php`?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yeah, 404.php present in my root directory and that the reason some of my wrong url working perfectly and some (mainly ending with .php) not working.

Comment: Somebody please help me with headpain, 404 not working with url ending with .php?

Answer (score 1):

I found that if this happens if you use PHP-FPM, switching to PHP FAST-CGI served by Apache works for the cases above.

My .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
```

[Plesk PHP Setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UzQWU.png)

I found this workaround from Plesk Support https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/213912945-After-switching-a-website-to-FPM-served-by-nginx-in-Plesk-it-fails-to-load-with-404-Not-Found-on-all-pages-except-start-page